# why sometimes my blogger fonts are changing to something like times new roman or so?

Tags: fonts, blogger

it happens in mozilla and chrome but not always. most of times it does though
its rather strange, it happens any font i choose in blogger, it changes it. My blogger is efriend.gr

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **Arial** font family for your all post do below

CSS :-

```
.post-outer{ 
    font-family: arial;
}
```

If you want to use **Arial** font family for your whole body do below

CSS :-

```
.body{ 
    font-family: arial;
}
```

You can choose different font-family also.